# Метод перестановки, усложнённой по таблице

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, list, перестановка

Нужно реализовать метод перестановки, есть такой код, но вывод не тот, который нужен...

Примеры:

Ключ: 123456789
Текст: мама, папа и я
Вывод: мамамамамамамамама
Нужный вывод: маа миа ,я  п а п

======

Ключ: 123456789
Текст: молоко, арбуз и лимон
Вывод: молмолмолмолмолмолмолмолмол

======

Уже готовый код, всем спасибо за помощь и уделенное время!

```
#на этот эксперимент потрачено: 7,5 часов
print("Будем шифровать или расшифровывать? cif/decif") #print cif for encryption or decif for decryption
cipher=input()
print("Введите, пожалуйста, ключ: ") #print some int number
key=input()
print("Введите, пожалуйста, ваше предложение: ") #print your sentence for en\decryption
text=input()

def cryp(key, text):
    key_length = len(key)
    result = ""
    lines = len(text) // key_length + 1 # количество списков в вашей матрице
    for n in key: # каждая цифра из ключа
        for x in range(lines): # каждый список из воображаемой матрицы
            index = int(n) + (key_length * x - 1) # позиция в исходной строке
            try: # на случай выхода за пределы строки
                result = result + text[index]
            except:
                result = result + " " # если нужен пробел
                pass
    return result

def encryp(key, text):
    key_length = len(key)
    result = ""
    row = len(text) // key_length
    lines = len(text) // row # количество списков в вашей матрице
    q = 0
    i = 0
    j = 0
    x = str()
    ret = []
    matrix = [[0 for x in range(row)] for y in range(lines)] #Создаём матрицу
    for x in text:
        matrix[i][j] = x
        j=j+1
        if j%row == 0:
            j=0
            i=i+1
    while q != row:
        for n in key:
            ret += matrix[(int(n))-1][q]
        q=q+1
    sret = ''.join(ret)
    return sret

if cipher == "cif":
    print(cryp(key, text))
elif cipher == "decif":
    print(encryp(key, text))
else:
    print("Прошу прощения, но, видимо, где-то ошибка. Надеюсь, вы правильно всё написали. Приношу извинения за сбой!")
#Here is an apology for the fact that you or the program made a mistake somewhere
```

Comment: какова зависимость между ключом, текстом и результатом?

Comment: создаётся матрица, где массивы имеют такую же длину, что и длина ключа. Туда, в массивы, добавляются, пока не закончится место, элементы из текста, который был дан на вводе. Создаётся в матрице своеобразная табличка, состоящая из элементов текста, и, если последний массив не до конца заполнился(не хватило текста), то заполняется автоматом пустотой(вроде бы нулями). На выводе должен выйти массив, который будет переведён в строку, в который должны войти по элементу из каждого массива из матрицы(номер элемента - первая цифра ключа), потом ещё по элементу(вторая цифра ключа) и т.д.

Comment: у вас в примерах ключ 123456789 - реальный? как, используя его, можно получить "маа миа ,я п а п" из "мама, папа и я"? ps вы не ответили на вопрос Эникейщика: "какая зависимость между ключом, текстом и результатом"?

Comment: Длина ключа 123456789 =9. Значит длина массивов в матрице будет - 9. Длина текста "мама, папа и я" = 14. Первый массив будет таким: [мама, пап], второй [а и я0000]. Нули, потому что не хватило текста на массив. Первая цифра в ключе - 1, значит первыми на вывод берутся первые(нулевые) элементы из всех массивов, в данном примере - "м" и "а". Вторая цифра ключа - 2, значит вторыми на вывод берутся вторые(первые) элементы из всех массивов, "а" и "(пробел)". Уже на выводе имеется "маа ". И так далее, берём третью цифру ключа...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет необходимости создавать матрицы и перегружать код и голову. Достаточно сразу брать нужный символ из строки.

```
text = "мама, папа и я"
key = "123456789"
key_length = len(key)
result = ""
lines = len(text) // key_length + 1 # количество списков в вашей матрице

for n in key: # каждая цифра из ключа
    for x in range(lines): # каждый список из воображаемой матрицы
        index = int(n) + (key_length * x - 1) # позиция в исходной строке
        try: # на случай выхода за пределы строки
            result = result + text[index]
        except:
            # result = result + " " # если нужен пробел
            pass

print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def crypt(key: str, text: str) -> str:
    sep = 0
    parts = []
    len_key = len(key)
    len_text = len(text)

    while sep < len_text:                                  # запись частей текста в список строк
        parts.append(text[sep:sep+len_key])
        sep += len_key

    parts[-1] = parts[-1].ljust(len_key, ' ')              # дополнение последнего элемента пробелами
    crypt_list = [p[int(k)-1] for k in key for p in parts] # создание нового списка

    return ''.join(crypt_list)                             # возвращение объединенной строки
```

```
>>> crypt('123456789', 'мама, папа и я')
'маа миа ,я  п а п '

>>> crypt('123456789', 'молоко, арбуз и лимон')
'мрмоболуноз к  ои ,   л аи '
```